# Unexpected behavior with XSLT when trying to select first matching element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have data that I want to serialize to XML in a specific format.  I have an array of `TestClass`, which consists of two string properties: `A` and `B`.

I know that this doesn't sound like good practice, but in this case, I expect that the values of `A` are identical for all instances of `TestClass`.

I want to create an XML file that contains the common `A` value and all the `B` values.  I've written the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.IO;

namespace test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class TestClass
        {
            public string A { get; set; }
            public string B { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass[] array = new TestClass[]
            {
                new TestClass() { A = "A1", B="B1"},
                new TestClass() { A = "A2", B="B2"}
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass[]));
            XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();            
            xslt.Load("test.xslt");

            string xml1Name = @"c:\temp\xmltest\original.xml";
            string xml2Name = @"c:\temp\xmltest\transformed.xml";            

            using (FileStream xmlStream = new FileStream(xml1Name, FileMode.Create))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlStream, array);
            }
            xslt.Transform(xml1Name, xml2Name);
        }
    }
}
```

test.xslt contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>

  <xsl:template match="/ArrayOfTestClass/TestClass[1]">
    <Test>
      <A>
        <xsl:value-of select="A"/>
      </A>
      <B_Values>
        <xsl:for-each select="/ArrayOfTestClass/TestClass">
          <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="B" />
          </value>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </B_Values>
    </Test>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I expect that my code should output two files. The "default" serialization generated by the XMLSerializer class appears to be correct.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfTestClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TestClass>
    <A>A1</A>
    <B>B1</B>
  </TestClass>
  <TestClass>
    <A>A2</A>
    <B>B2</B>
  </TestClass>
</ArrayOfTestClass>
```

The XSLT transformed XML is almost correct, but it contains some extra trailing text, which appears to be the values of `A` and `B` in the second element of the serialized array.  This is not a typo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Test><A>A1</A><B_Values><value>B1</value><value>B2</value></B_Values></Test>

    A2
    B2
```

Why is my XSLT not generating the result that I expect?  How can I make it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) of XSLT, which are used in the case where the XSLT processor can't find a specific template in the stylesheet for the nodes it is trying to match. The built-in template for elements and the root node is to essentially skip over the element and look for templates that match it children. If it finds a text node, it will output the text.

In your XSLT, you do not have a template matching either `/` or the `ArrayOfTestClass` element, and so the built-in templates kick-in. If the case of `ArrayOfTestClass` it will look for templates that match ALL its child nodes, but you only have a specific template matching the first child node. Thus the other `TestClass` elements will be matched by the built-in template, and ultimately the text within them is output.

All you need to do is add a template to tell XSLT to stop-processing the other `TestClass` elements. You could just add this template

```
<xsl:template match="/ArrayOfTestClass/TestClass[position() > 1]" />
```

However, if you are only ever going to have `TestClass` elements as child nodes of `ArrayOfTestClass` elements, you could simplify it to this

```
<xsl:template match="TestClass" />
```

This takes advantage of the fact XSLT will give priority to the more specific template when multiple templates may match the same element.